# Any way to run a vim session over salt-ssh?

Tags: linux, saltstack

Anyone know of a way to interact with the console/terminal over a `salt-ssh` command? I'm trying to run `vim` to change the subnet and FQDN for about 70 hosts. I could use `sed` and company but wondering if we can leverage `salt-ssh` for this task. Below, salt runs the command, but I can't interact with vim.

```
# salt-ssh '*' cmd.run 'vi /etc/hosts'
s^C
Exiting gracefully on Ctrl-c

Exiting gracefully on Ctrl-c

Exiting gracefully on Ctrl-c
```

Comment: it doesn't seem that salt-ssh expect to open an interactive shell with the minion, but running the command under an ssh connection.
I don't have a working salt infrastructure right now, but you may try to run it with -t (or tty=true in roster conf) and execute `bash` to see if it spawns a shell instance. Yet I'm sceptical on if it works.

Comment: No luck with`tty:true` or `salt-ssh -t` .  That gives me something to dig into however, thanks.